# The meaning of “Yards divided by minutes,”

Tags: meaning

> So far I have not told the story of the things of Llantrisant, but
>   rather the story of how I stumbled upon them and among them, perplexed
>   and wholly astray, seeking, but yet not knowing at all what I sought;
>   bewildered now and again by circumstances which seemed to me wholly
>   inexplicable; devoid, not so much of the key to the enigma, but of the
>   key to the nature of the enigma. You cannot begin to solve a puzzle
>   till you know what the puzzle is about. **“Yards divided by minutes,”
>   said the mathematical master to me long ago, “will give neither pigs,
>   sheep, nor oxen.”** He was right; though his manner on this and on all
>   other occasions was highly offensive. This is enough of the personal
>   process, as I may call it; and here follows the story of what happened
>   at Llantrisant last summer, the story as I pieced it together at last.

This is from “The Great Return” by Atthur Macken, 
https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/m/machen/arthur/great-return/chapter4.html

I don’t understand th meaning of this sentence. 
“Yards divided by minutes will give neither pigs, sheep, nor oxen.”

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

Yard is a measure of length, minutes is a measure of time, so yards divided by minutes gives a measure of speed, not a count of sheep or oxen etc.

There is no special idiom here, just the normal literal meaning of the words.  It is called "offensive" perhaps because it is sarcastic.